# NSAttributedString from RTF works only with iOS 8, not with iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitextview, rtf, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to load an RTF-File in a UITextView with the following Code:

```
NSURL * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:_fileName withExtension:@"rtf"];

NSAttributedString *stringWithRTFAttributes = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:filePath options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
myTextView.attributedText = stringWithRTFAttributes;
```

With iOS 8 it works perfectly, but on iOS 7 it doesn't work, it only displays the Text without attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it saving the RTF-Files as HTML (with TextEdit) and changed the code to

```
NSURL * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:_fileName withExtension:@"html"];

NSAttributedString *stringWithHTMLAttributes = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithFileURL:filePath options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
myTextView.attributedText = stringWithHTMLAttributes;
```

Comment: Does it work with iOS8.0? I get "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector", while it does work with later 8.x builds!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't an iOS 8.0 Device, but the Deployment Target is set to 7.0. I think, it's a runtime Error? Maybe somebody has an iOS 8.0 Device and can test it??